# Unable to Load an IIS based webservice more than 30% CPU.

Tags: jmeter, throughput

1. I am load testing an IIS based webservice
2. I need to find out what max. throughput it can support
3. both the server and the load generators are setup in AWS
4. The problem is that throughput of the webservice is not going beyond 1500 req/sec even on increasing the users from 500 to 3000, only response time increases (PS: i am using 15GB ram 8 core AWS machines for load generation).
5. Eore wierd part is CPU usage is not 100%, it is merely30-40%
6. Even the memory utilization is not high it is 20%.
7. I tried many counters in PerfMon and did not see anything which could show possible bottleneck
8. When I use a single machine to generate load it shows ~1500 throughput, if I add one more load generator then the throughput visibly drops to half on the original machine, still giving me a combined total of ~1500 requests/sec.

WHat am I missing here?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: You're clearly being limited by something other than hardware resources. I would check application config limits. Concurrent thread limits, DB connection pool limits etc.

Comment: Thanks RaGe.  Kindly elaborate a little. DB connection pool limit is 500 and we do not see more then 100-200 connections. Where should i look for concurrent thread limits? Which App config limits could cause this kind of throtteling

Comment: Also, is it possible that there is some configuration issue at the JMeter test that I have written. We are also using a load balancer of AWS. Is it possible JMeter has any known issue in loading an AWS load balanced server

Comment: When you split your JMeter load across two machines, you didn't get 1500/sec in each - which points to the limit not being on the jmeter end - clearly your JMeter setup is capable of atleast 1500/sec. The problem is likely on the other end - possibly application setup, but could even be network or loadbalancer. I'm not intimately familiar with the IIS world to give you specific recommendations, but there should be configurable/tunable limits for max concurrent connections, max process memory etc. Is your application running on .net CLR?

Comment: This post is a very late one. but still thought of sharing the reason. The mistake was mine, the requests were running in sequence and a previous request with slower throughput was the bottleneck for the other requests, thanks for your replies and time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the IIS configurations and thread pool settings in IIS. This is quite
   known issue. If available threads are less and even if CPU or memory
   is available throughput wont grow as the requests are queued up waiting.
2. Also check processor queue length counter in perfmon. It could be
   some IO issue if the queue is long throughout the test